# Bounding derivative of a function

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis, derivatives

Consider $a(t)\in\mathbf{L}^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and $a(t)>0$, is a low pass smooth function with $\hat{a}(f)=0, |f|>f_{max}$. Can we have a upper bound on the following,
$\Big|\frac{a'(t)}{a(t)}\Big|$?
Using Bernstien's theorem we can upper bound $|a'(t)|$ alone based on $f_{max}$ but how can we upper bound the ratio mentioned here. Any suggestions for it.

Comment: What is $L(\mathbb{R})$? What is $a$?

Comment: Edited the question, now no typos.

Comment: How did you find the bound using Bernstein's Theorem?

Comment: In the case I am dealing with, only real zeros of $a(t)$ are of interest. 
Now taking a simple example, $a(t)=1+\mu\sin\omega t$, with $0<\mu<1$ we have,\newline
$\Big|\frac{a'(t)}{a(t)}\Big|=\frac{\mu\omega\cos\omega t}{1+\mu\sin\omega t}\leq\frac{\mu\omega}{\sqrt{1-\mu^2}}, \forall t$.

So above it can be bounded, though a simple example. Can we have a bound for sum of harmonic sinusoids and generalize it.

Comment: @ dexter04: Based on Bernstein's theorem, $|a'(t)|\leq2f_{max} |a_{max}|$.